# Is it allowed per the oAuth2 specs to have multiple valid tokens per Resource Owner at the same time?

Tags: oauth-2.0

According to the [oAuth2 specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), Is it allowed to have multiple valid tokens per Resource Owner at the same time?

For security considerations it seems appropriate (less exposed area for replay attacks) that only 1 active token per Resource Owner (i.e: User) is available. This would mean that when a new access token is requested for a Resource Owner the existing/old one (if exists) should be revoked.

I can't find any mention of this mechanism. Can someone clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen no such restriction in the standard. Having multiple tokens absolutely makes sense and may even improve security for tokens with different scopes. Consider a scenario when the client starts with some basic privileges (e.g. read-only access) and asks for elevated privileges for sensitive operations (e.g. write access). This is very similar to "run as root/admin" in linux/win systems.

Consequently, having multiple tokens with different scopes can make a system more secure if a single token is stolen.

Comment: That makes sense, but assumes scopes would be strictly partitioned. (i.e: there intersection would be empty). I'd always imagined to model a scope with elevated privileges E to contain the scope of basic privileges B. (i.e: E is a superset of B). In this way you would only need 1 scope/client. Do you have any references to best practices in modeling scopes in the way you mention (or at all)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have references. You're mostly right about partitioning scopes, but not completely. First, access tokens expire shortly, so even using your B/E model is not that serious IMHO. You should take more care about refresh tokens. Having refresh token(s) for the absolutely required offline scopes (and only access tokens for the rest) may be a good way to go.

Comment: ah yes ok that makes sense. Also having separate expiration policies for B and E (E would expire faster for example) would be possible with multiple tokens like you suggest. Thanks.